# How can i pass parameters from method to action in vuejs vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have to files with this code:

Users.vue

```
methods: {
obtenerUsuarios() {
  console.log('Obtener Usuarios')
  this.$store
    .dispatch('auth/getValidToken')
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data). // Console First Message
      this.$store
        .dispatch('user/fetchUsers', data)
        .then((response) => {
          this.items = response.data
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error: ' + error)
    })
},
```

},

Console Firsts Mesagge show me a json web token in console that is ok.
When i dispatch 'user/fetchUsers in

user.js

```
export const actions = {
    fetchUsers({ jwt }) {
    console.log('Action JWT:' + jwt)  //Second console.log
    return UserService.getUsers(jwt)
  },
}
```

The second messaje show me: ***Action JWT:undefined*** in the console

if i change the line two to

```
fetchUsers(jwt) {
```

The second messaje show me: ***Action JwT:[object Object]***

I need to pass a json web token from Users.vue method to fetchUsers action y user.js

I will to appreciate any help

Jose Rodriguez

Comment: What does jwt show if you do `fetchUsers(jwt) { console.log(jwt) }`?

Comment: Hi, jwt show {getters: {…}, state: {…}, rootGetters: {…}, dispatch: ƒ, commit: ƒ, …}

Comment: What is the code for your auth/getValidToken action?

Comment: getValidToken() {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
    const time = user.created
    const now = new Date().getTime()

    var sec_diff = (now - time) / 1000
    const remainingTime = 1800 - sec_diff
    if (remainingTime > 60) {
      //return jwt
      return user.jwt
    }
    return remainingTime
    // request jwt
  },

Comment: getValidToken returns a valid token as i expect, the problem is how can i pas from the method to the action

Comment: So your "request jwt" sends off a http request and returns the token which you then save to the user in user.jwt? Do you return that promise in your action? For example `return axios.get('/token').then((response) => ( // return token from response ))`. Does `remainingTime > 60` ever get hit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212742/discussion-between-pillo-and-hides).

Comment: You get `Action JwT:[object Object]` because you are using a `+` in your console change it to `,` ```fetchUsers(jwt ) {
    console.log('Action JWT:', jwt)  //Second console.log
    return UserService.getUsers(jwt)
  }```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action method currently declares the data in the first argument (and no second argument), but [actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#actions) receive the Vuex context as its *first* argument. The data payload is in the *second* argument:

```js
const actions = {
  //fetchUsers(data) {}        // DON'T DO THIS (1st arg is for context)
  fetchUsers(context, data) {}
}
```